# List comprehension in Python, how to

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am reading about Python and I want to do a problem with list comprehensions. The problem is simple:

> Write a program that gives the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 before some n
>
> Take n = 1000 (Euler project, 1st problem)

I want to do something like this:

```
[mysum = mysum + i for i in range(2,1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0]
```

With only one line... But that does not work.

1. Can this can be achieved with list comprehensions? How?
2. Also, when is it good to use list comprehensions?

Comment: Your problem description says you are filtering multiples of 3 and 5, but your code is filtering multiples of 2 and 5.

Comment: @Edwardo: As a note on the terminology used in your comments, you keep contrasting list comprehensions to "functional programming". List comprehensions came to Python from Haskell. Algorithms that use iterators as a lazy list are also straight out of Haskell and related languages. Using a chain of generator expressions to express the stages of your computation is still a functional style, or maybe functional-declarative; the fact that you're using bare expressions instead of declared functions doesn't really make it any less functional; just less Lisp-y.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point of list comprehensions is to generate a list of result values, one per source value (or one per *matching* source value, if you have `if` clauses).

In other words, it's the same thing as `map` (or a chain of `map` and `filter` calls, if you have multiple clauses), except that you can describe each new value as an expression in terms of the old value, instead of having to wrap that up in a function.

You can't put a statement (like `mysum = mysum + i`) into a comprehension, only an expression. And, even if you can come up with an expression that has the side-effect you want, that would still be a confusing misuse of the comprehension. If you don't want a list of result values, don't use a list comprehension.

If you're just trying to perform a computation in a loop, write an explicit `for` loop.

---

If you really need it to be one line, you can always do this:

```
for i in [i for i in range(2, 10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0]: mysum += i
```

Build the list of things to loop over with a comprehension; do the side-effect-y calculation in a `for` loop.

(Of course that's assuming you've already got some value in `mysum` to add on to, e.g., using `mysum = 0`.)

And, in general, whenever you want a comprehension just for looping over once, the kind of comprehension you want is a generator expression, not a list comprehension. So, turn those square brackets into parentheses, and you get this:

```
for i in (i for i in range(2, 10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0): mysum += i
```

Either way, though, it's more readable and pythonic as two lines:

```
for i in (i for i in range(2, 10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0):
    mysum += i
```

… or even three:

```
not2or5 = (i for i in range(2, 10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0) 
for i in not2or5:
    mysum += i
```

---

If you're coming from a language that makes `reduce`/`fold` more intuitive to you than loops, Python has a `reduce` function. However, it's generally not considered Pythonic to use it just to eliminate `for` loops and turn block statements into one-liners.

More generally, trying to cram things into a single line usually makes things less readable, not more, in Python, and often means you end up with more characters to type and more tokens to process in your head, which more than cancels out any gain in saving lines.

---

Of course in this specific case, all you really want to do is sum up the values of a list. And that's exactly what `sum` does. And that's trivial to understand. So:

```
mysum += sum(i for i in range(2, 10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0)
```

(Again, this is assuming you already have something in `mysum` you want to add onto. If not, just change the `+=` to an `=`. The same is true for all of the later examples, so I'll stop explaining it.)

---

All that being said, I'd probably write this either as an explicit nested block:

```
for i in range(2, 10):
    if i%2==0 or i%5==0:
        mysum += i
```

… or as a sequence of iterator transformations (which in this case is really just one transformation):

```
not2or5 = (i for i in range(2, 10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0)
mysum += sum(not2to5)
```

There's really no cost to splitting things up this way (as long as you use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions), and it usually makes the intent of your code a lot more obvious.

---

Some further explanation on generator expressions:

A generator expression is just like a list comprehension, except that it builds an iterator instead of a list. An iterator is similar to a "lazy list" in some functional languages, except that you can only use it once. (Usually, that's not a problem. In all the examples above, the only thing we want to do is pass it to the `sum` function or use it in a `for` loop, and then we never refer to it again.) As you iterate over it, each value is constructed on demand, and then freed before you get to the next one.

This means the space complexity is constant, instead of linear. You've only ever got one value in memory at a time, whereas with a list you've obviously got all of them. That's often a huge win.

However, the time complexity is unchanged. A list comprehension does all the work up front, so it's linear time to build, then free to use. A generator expression does the work as you iterate over it, so it's free to build, then linear to use. Either way, same time. (A generator expression can actually be significantly faster in practice, because of cache/memory locality, pipelining, etc., not to mention avoiding all the memory moving and allocation costs. On the other hand, it's slower for trivial cases, at least in CPython, because it has to go through the full iterator protocol instead of the quick special-casing for lists.)

(I'm assuming here that the work for each step is constant—obviously `[sum(range(i)) for i in range(n)]` is quadratic in n, not linear…)

Comment: abarnett, many thanks! But I think that you have a typo in the first 2 examples. mysum must be declared first, I think. Same thing with las example. In the 3rd example (which look good) must be '=' not '+=' . What you mean by a generation expression? it has the same big-O? I want just to write good code with Python :) I know how map and reduce works (at least). I writed some code in Racket (a dialect of Scheme). I will post my two line code using this functional programming tools. Please, tell what do you think and which will be the best way to do it in terms of big-O analisis.

Comment: @Edwardo: Your original code doesn't specify an initial value for `mysum`, it just adds things on to whatever's there. So, I wrote my code to do the same thing. If that wasn't what you wanted, I'll edit my answer for it.

Comment: @Edwardo: For the second half of your question… it's too hard to explain in a comment, so I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: What about the complexity (big-O)?

Comment: @Edwardo: I explained the big-O complexity, just in words instead of symbols. Iterating a list comprehension is linear, or `O(N)`, time and space; iterating a generator expression is linear, or `O(N)`, time, but constant, or `O(1)`, space. (In case it isn't clear, `sum` iterates over whatever you pass it, and so does an explicit `for` loop.)

Comment: Ok thanks!!! I learned a lot here! Either way, as you say in your post, the "nature for" without list/generator expression is better in big O O(n). Many thanks! Note: sorry, my browser was not updated to see your comment

Comment: Another advantage of generators is the ability to short-circuit tests such as `all` or `any` - passing a million-item list to `all` will have to build a 1,000,000 element list first before starting to look at the values. A 1,000,000 element generator passed to `all` will stop at the first False value.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Yes, good point. It also means you can write infinitely-long iterators as long as you don't plan to consume the whole thing—`squares = (i**2 for i in itertools.count())` is useful; `squares = [i**2 for i in itertools.count()]` is a guaranteed `MemoryError`.

Comment: @Edwardo: A natural for is the exact same big O as a generator expression, O(n) time and O(1) space. If you want to do something to each of n values, no matter how you do it, that's going to be O(n), unless you can find some way to combine multiple values into a single operation.

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there!  Try this:

```
mysum = sum([i for i in range(2,10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0])
```

This will create a list out of the "loop", then pass this list to the `sum` function.

A list comprehension like `mylist = [*some expression using i* for i in iterable]` is a shorthand for

```
mylist = []
for i in iterable:
    mylist.append(*some expression using i*)
```

A list comprehension like `mylist = [*some expression using i* for i in iterable if *boolean with i*]` is a shorthand for

```
mylist = []
for i in iterable:
    if *boolean with i*:
        mylist.append(*some expression using i*)
```

You can use these whenever you need to construct a *new* list using some expression.  List comprehensions are actually typically more efficient than an equivalent `for` loop because they execute the code in `C` underneath the hood, instead of through interpreted Python.

Comment: Woow, the power of python! Thanks!! @SethMMorton

Comment: You can't put a _statement_ in a listcomp (or as an argument an `append` call), only an _expression_. This is a very important distinction in Python.

Comment: Thanks! what means the * in the boolean and i variables??

Comment: @abarnert Yup.  Good catch. Editing.  I had an icky feeling when I wrote statement, I couldn't think of the right word.

Comment: @Edwardo It was my way of saying "insert your appropriate code here" using something syntactically invalid in python so it would be obvious where you should substitute your commands.

Comment: @SethMMorton thanks to both! But finally then, which is the best way? just a natural for loop? because sum is adding O(n) right? Or as my answer with functional programming? what is the complexity (big-O) of the generating expression? Thanks!

Comment: @Edwardo See my edit.  You can use a generator instead of a list comprehension if you ultra are concerned about efficiency/mememory: `mysum = sum(i for i in range(2,10) if i%2==0 or i%5==0)`.  I omitted  the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two-line implementation with filter, sum and reduce:

```
def f(x): return x%3 == 0 or x%5 == 0
print sum(filter(f,range(2,1000)))
```

Nice, right? Can you explain me a little bit this code:

```
not2or5 = (i for i in range(2, 1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0)
print sum(not2or5)
```

Comment: You are creating a generator (`()` instead  of `[]`).  Instead of making a loop, it creates an object that only returns values when requested by some calling function.

Comment: Any call to `map` or `filter` is equivalent to a list comprehension (or, in Python 3.x, a generator expression), except that you have to wrap the expression or predicate in a function. I tried to explain that in my answer; if it's still not clear, you should read a tutorial on the subject. The official tutorial has a section on [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and a section on [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) that might get you started, but there are probably more novice-friendly explanations.

Comment: I have a couple of oneliners: print sum([x for x in xrange(1,1000) if x%3==0 or x%5==0]) or this one: print sum([[0,x][x%3==0 or x%5==0] for x in xrange(1,10**3)])