# Mixed data in 2D list

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter, 2d

I have a 2D list which I have added several lines.  Each line consists of a string and then 3 floats.

```py
filmRatings = [ [ "Lion", 9.8, 7.2 , 9.5 ] ]
filmRatings.append( ["Transformers" , 3.7 , 6.8 , 5.2] )
filmRatings.append( ["Pirates of the Caribbean" , 6.1 , 4.9 , 7.3] )
filmRatings.append( ["Moana" , 8.2 , 7.9 , 6.7] )
filmRatings.append( ["War Games" , 7.3 , 8.1 , 7.7] )
    
print(filmRatings)

total = 0.0
for i in range(len(filmRatings[0])):
    total = total + filmRatings[0][i]
    print(total)
```

I would like to add together the float values in the first row [0] only, but need to avoid the string value in [0][0].
Essentially what I want to do is simply want to ignore the string elements of the list and add up the floats, perhaps some kind of filter is the way to go, but I wasn’t sure as I know there are several ways to skin a cat as they say.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want to do is simply want to ignore the string elements of the list

Array slicing is the perfect tool for this job.

In each of your lists the 0th element is a string

```py
example_list = [ "Lion", 9.8, 7.2 , 9.5 ]
```

So what you want to do is slice that list

```
print(example_list[1:len(example_list)]) # [9.8, 7.2, 9.5]
```

As you can see here this `[index1:index2]` syntax selects items of a list starting from index `index1 - 1` and ending at `index2 - 1`. So **it starts counting at `1` not at `0`**.

So in your case all you simply have to do is

```
total = 0.0
# Here creating a new array consisting only of the numbers without the string 
filmRatingsWithoutString = filmRatings[0][1:len(filmRatings[0])]
for i in range(len(filmRatingsWithoutString)):
    total = total + filmRatingsWithoutString[i]
    print(total)
```

One more thing.

Instead of using `example_list[1:len(example_list)]` you can just simply use `example_list[1:]` to continue until the end.

> perhaps some kind of filter is the way to go

if you want to do this with **filtering** as you said, you can just simply use an `if` statement to check if the value is a string and then continue as normal.

```
# Only allow strings here
filmRatingsWithoutString = [
    item for item in filmRatings[0] if type(item) != str
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, essentially creating a new list from the position 1 of the original list, thereby ignoring the strings.

Comment: or just creating a new list and then appending everything that is not a string, therefore "filtering".

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the list and get all the float number by using list comprehension

```
[i for i in filmRatings[0] if type(i) is float]
```

you can add them by using sum function like this

```
sum([i for i in filmRatings[0] if type(i) is float])
```

Comment: Ok, I get it I just created new variables and viola, I am still a little perplexed about the square brackets in the list comprehension. Thanks again for your help

Comment: you can read more about list comprehension at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104760/list-comprehension-in-python-how-to