# Meaning of: urlTags = [t[11:] for t in tags if t.startswith('site_url')]

Tags: python

I'm a novice beginner with python, and I'm trying to understand a piece of code that I can't really get the answer to. Can someone explain how the following works?

```
urlTags = [t[11:] for t in tags if t.startswith('site_url')]
```

I know that this is slice notation, but I'm struggling to understand what the

```
'[t['
```

and t in tags part is doing. Any explanation would be helpful!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104760/list-comprehension-in-python-how-to

Answer (score 1):

`[t[11:] for t in tags if t.startswith('site_url')]`
Means for each item in the list `tags` that starts with `site_url`, take the string from the 11th index forward

So lets say the list `tags` is
`tags = ['site_url://www.facebook.com', 'blabla', 'site_url://www.amazon.com']`

The result will be `['www.facebook.com', 'www.amazon.com']`

Answer (score 0):

This is called list comprehension.
It will return a list object that contains individual elements of the list tags if the element in question meets the criteria of the if statement (in this case if the element starts with 'site_url').
Finally the element that will be added in this new list will be sliced, starting from the 11th caracter to its end. Please see Python list slicing rules / documentation for more details.