# getting part of dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries

```
teachers = [

    {
        "id": 0,
        "goals": ["travel", "relocate", "study"],
    },

    {
        "id": 1,
        "goals": ["travel","study"],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "goals": ["travel", "work", "study"],
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "goals": ["work", "relocate", "study"],
    }
]
```

I need to get part of dictionary where in "work" is in list in "goals" :

```
teachers = [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "goals": ["travel", "work", "study"],
    },

    {
        "id": 3,
        "goals": ["work", "relocate", "study"],
    }
]
```

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: `print([x for x in teachers if "work" in x["goals"]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most compact solution is to use list comprehensions

```py
teachers = [t for t in teachers if "work" in t["goals"]]
```

[List comprehension in python, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104760/list-comprehension-in-python-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`, the built-in function.

It returns an iterator, which minimized the overhead of list comprehension. If you only need a plain list as the result, just wrap it with a `list()`

```
>>> list(filter(lambda o:"work" in o["goals"], teachers))
[{'id': 2, 'goals': ['travel', 'work', 'study']}, {'id': 3, 'goals': ['work', 'relocate', 'study']}]
```

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score -2):

Get the dictionary by pointing to it's index in the list.

```
print(teachers[3])

>>>{'id': 3, 'goals': ['work', 'relocate', 'study']}
```