# Mark duplicate element in string

Tags: python, syntax

```
res=[val+str(test[:idx].count(val)+1) if test.count(val)>1 else val for idx,val in enumerate(test)]
```

Can anyone please explain this syntax elaborately?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List Comprehension Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104760/list-comprehension-in-python-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the code :-

```
res=[val+str(test[:idx].count(val)+1) if test.count(val)>1 else val for idx,val in enumerate(test)]
```

1. `for idx,val in enumerate(test)` :- It's enumerating through the string test, i.e iterating the characters along with the index number. Here `val` is the characters from `test` list and `idx` is the corresponding index.
2. `val+str(test[:idx].count(val)+1) if test.count(val)>1 else val` : Consider this as `X if Y else Z`, so if the condition `Y` is satisfied then `X` will be executed and passed else `Z`
3. `val+str(test[:idx].count(val)+1)` :- Here you are concatenating the character `val` from the string `test` and the number of occurences of the character `val` in the slice of string i.e substring starting from 0 index till idx index

Hopefully, you got the breakdowns.

I will edit and add the code for more clarification in some time.